# How to run Multi-Threading for function within function - Python

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, python-multithreading

## Python beginner!!

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

devices = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2']

def conn(device):
    connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', 
                             username='kiran', ip=device, password='ciscossh',secret='ciscoen')
    print 'connection successful'
    def commmand():
        value = connect.send('sh int ip brief')
        print value

for device in devices:
   thread = Thread(target = conn, args = (device, ))
   thread.start()
   thread.join()
   print("thread finished...exiting")
```

output :

connection successful

thread finished...exiting

connection successful

thread finished...exiting

Issue: Not reading second function command(), Is it required to call second function which is inside the first one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ***is*** reading `command()` and building the function. You just never use this function after defining it. I suggest you [review functions in python](https://www.codementor.io/kaushikpal/user-defined-functions-in-python-8s7wyc8k2)

Your code needs to be adjusted:

```
def conn(device):
    connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', 
                             username='kiran', ip=device, password='ciscossh',secret='ciscoen')
    print 'connection successful'
    def commmand():
        value = connect.send('sh int ip brief')
        print value
    command() # call your function!!! otherwise it is useless...
```

Answer (score 0):

shall I try to clarify some points that might be helpful for you.

**-** Even though you are defining the `command()` method, it is not being explicitly called, so its answer should certainly not be printed out.

**-** The way your threads are working right now is quite synchronous. When you use `join()`, it blocks the execution of the thread until it finishes and, since you do not have other threads initialized simultaneously, your code execution is still straightforward. If it matches your interest, you may consider launching all the threads and then join them **after** the *for* loop.

**-** Network connections sometimes require independent core resources, and have separate processor or memory requirements. In this case, you might want to explore Python's *multiprocessing* module instead of *threading*.

**-** If you are interested in launching multiple threads|processes, each for every iteration (*for* loop), you might want to consider using `Pool` objects, which make multiple threads available for you in a single data structure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, it will help.

Comment: Is it same using " multiprocessing " ??